# Generic Repository 'Find' Method with Expression

Tags: c#, .net, repository, clean-architecture

In one of the courses I found in Udemy regarding clean architecture, there is this structure;
(I am omitting unnecessary methods for brevity)

A generic repository interface

`IRepository`

```
...
IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
...
```

`Repository.cs`

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    return _db.Set<T>().Where(expression);
}
```

`IProductRepository` which implements `IRepository<Product>` defining the methods that are going to be used from the repository.

Then in the service layer;

`IProductService` interface

then

`ProductService` class that implements the `IProductService` interface.

Omitting the code for AutoMapper; with standard methods such as "GetAll", I can have a method in the `ProductService` class such as:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> GetAll()
{
    return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>>(_productRepository.GetAllProducts());
}
```

In a controller in somewhere else, I can inject the `IProductService` and use the methods with no problem such as `_productService.GetAll();`

My question is, I can't figure out how I am supposed to be using the Find method as given above. I don't know how to pass in an expression to a service and get it converted by AutoMapper to form a query. The course does not mention anything about this also.

Up until now, what I tried was creating alternate methods for my find scenarios but obviously this just creates unnecessary and bloated code.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't EF already implement something like this?

Comment: EF Implements this but I am using a multi-layered architecture where I use the service layer to pass my request to the repository. My service layer does not know anything about EF.

Comment: AutoMapper should have nothing to do with passing the expression to the repository since it's just mapping the returned results. Can you show what code you've tried so far to use `Find()` in the service layer, and include any errors that you receive?

Comment: @devNull basically I need to convert/map the `ProductViewModel`  to my DbSet Product class: Find(Expression<Func<ProductViewModel, bool>> expression)

Comment: You shouldn't be using Find on view models, but on your entity/data models. Then the expression has the right types and you map the result of Find

Comment: I am not using Find on viewmodels. I need to pass the expression as view model to my service layer which then has to somehow translate the expression so I can send it to the repository!

Comment: The point was that you should be translating before your service layer, not in your service layer. Then the expression can have the expected type before hand